# Cannot set property 'username' of null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, error-handling, passport.js

Having an error where a logged in user will try to update their account username but run into an error. For the life of me I cannot figure out why it is sometimes (maybe 1/20 users run into this) unable to find the current user. User's can only access this page if logged in. **The errors are:**

> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>
> TypeError: Cannot set property 'username' of null

The error seems to be happening here: *user.username = req.body.username;*

```
router.post("/updateAccount", function (req, res) {
    if (req.user) {
        User.findOne({username: req.body.currentUser}, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            user.username = req.body.username;
            user.save(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    req.flash("error", "It looks like that email address is taken.");
                    res.redirect('back')
                } else {
                    req.logout();
                    req.login(user, function (err) {
                        if (err) console.log('There was an account error' + err)
                        req.flash("success", "Your account has been created! Your username is " + user.username);
                        res.redirect('/results')

                    });
                }
            });
        });

    } else {
        res.redirect('/results')
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user` will be null if no matching user can be found by the `User.findOne({username: req.body.currentUser}` query (as mentioned in the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne)).

So you should add another check if that's the case and handle this appropriately:

```
User.findOne({username: req.body.currentUser}, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            if (!user) {
                // handle this case as user.username = req.body.username will fail
            }
            // ... rest of the code
```

Comment: Thanks very much @elo! This is helpful. Any idea why that would happen to a user who is currently logged in? Maybe the user session was lost?

Comment: If the session were lost `req.user` would be undefined I think. So as far as I understand it it is actually ok for user to be null, since that means that no user exists with the desired username that was passed in the request-body. Or am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: That's spot on. The thing throwing me off is that the user is currently logged in when they attempt to update their username. Meaning as far as I can tell there is no reason the user should not be found. hmm

Comment: Actually it's not querying the DB for the logged-in user, instead it queries the DB for the passed username in the request-body. I don't know your frontend/client code, but `req.body.currentUser` can contain arbitrary values, i.e. user-names that don't exist yet.

Comment: Ah! That just might be the issue. I was not aware of that. Thank you very much!